# HTTPS POST request Python, returning .csv

Tags: python, post, https, urllib, httplib

I want to make a post request to a HTTPS-site that should respond with a .csv file. I have this Python code:

```
try:
    #conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host="www.site.com", port=443)
```

=> Gives an BadStatusLine: ' ' error

```
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.site.com");
    params  = urllib.urlencode({'val1':'123','val2':'abc','val3':'1b3'})
    conn.request("POST", "/nps/servlet/exportdatadownload", params)
    content = conn.getresponse()
    print content.reason, content.status
    print content.read()
    conn.close()
except:
    import sys
    print sys.exc_info()[:2]
```

Output:

```
Found 302

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>302 Found</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Found</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.site.com/nps/servlet/exportdatadownload">here</A>.<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.3.5.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server Server at mp-www1.mrco.be Port 7778</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I 'catch' the returning .csv file?
I tried the POST request with an Chrome Extentions (Advanced Rest Client, and that's working...)

Comment: As the error shows, the web server wants you to access the url over https - what is the exact error when you try to establish an HTTPSConnection?

Comment: On the command line, what does the following command give you? `curl -XPOST 'https://www.site.com/nps/servlet/exportdatadownload?val1=123&val2=abc&val3=1b3'`

Comment: @Ali-AkberSaifee : `(<class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>, BadStatusLine("''",))`

Answer (score 1):

The HTML output with the 302 error is because you're connecting to the site using HTTP instead of HTTPS, which is in your code here:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.site.com");
```

Presumably you're doing that because of some other error with the commented out section of your code.

If I were trying to do this I would use [Requests](http://github.com/kennethreitz/requests), which comes with very clear [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).  With Requests the code would be something like:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.example.com/nps/servlet/exportdatadownload"
payload = { "val1": "123", "val2": "abc", "val3": "1b3" }
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=True)
```

The CSV file should be in r.content, which can be written to a file.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect! Thought I was going to have to wade through coldfusion crap all day. Took 15 minutes to complete what would have been an 8 hour manual downloading task.

Comment: I've updated this to use example.com and add the verify parameter.  Also note that using this code with Python 3 attention will need to be paid to whether the response data (r.content) is binary or unicode strings/data.  Other than that it's unchanged.