# POST request (securely) to download CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, post, https

I'm trying to automate the download of a report through first logging in with username and password, then submitting a subsequent POST request.

I do not want to use a GET request, as this displays my credentials in the URL, and the history is saved in the browser. Further, the URL does not end in '.csv', so I cannot pass this directly in pd.read_csv('www.something.csv').

I've spend a lot of time looking at links, and the following one seems to be what I need, but my csv is not to be found in web_return.content.

[HTTPS POST request Python, returning .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057847/https-post-request-python-returning-csv)

```
report_id = '45'

payload = {'un': 'user.com',
               'pw': 'password',
               'export': 'Export',
               'enc': 'UTF-8',
               'xf': 'localecsv',
               'colDt_s': '1/1/2018',
               'colDt_e': '1/1/2019'}

web_return = requests.post('https://website.com/{}'.format(report_id),
                               data=payload).content

print(web_return)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(web_return.decode('utf-8')))
```

I wish for the df at the end to be the resulting CSV as a pandas dataframe. I have this working in another way, but I feel like this is something I should be able to do, and I want to do it the correct way. The current output is indeed a dataframe, but is not the correct contents:

```
print(df)

0                                              <html>                                                    
1                                              <head>                                                    
2       <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">                                                    
3                                            <script>                                                    
4   if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNav...                                                    
5                      if (window.location.replace){                                                     
6   window.location.replace('https://login.website...                                                    
7                                           } else {;                                                    
8   window.location.href ='https://login.website...                                                    
9                                                  }                                                     
10                                          </script>                                                    
11                                            </head>                                                    
12                                            </html>                                                    
13                               <!-- Body events -->                                                    
14  <script type="text/javascript">function bodyOn...                                                    
15                                            </body>                                                    
16                                            </html>                                                    
17                                               <!--                                                    
18  .................................................                                                    
19  .................................................                                                    
20  .................................................                                                    
21  .................................................                                                    
22                                                -->
```

Any help?

Thanks a million.

-- Update, thanks to @Barmar, I have been able to submit my request to the Javascript, but it tells me that I do not have Javascript enabled:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
<body>
<script>var tm=null;function lhdoredir(){tm&& . 
(window.clearTimeout(tm),tm=null);window.location.replace?       window.location.replace("https://login.website.com/45"):window.location.href="https://login.website.com/45"}window.setTimeout?tm=window.setTimeout(lhdoredir,1E3):lhdoredir()
You do not have Javascript enabled. Javascript is required to use 
website.com. Please enable Javascript, then click <a 
href="https://login.website.com/45">here</a> to continue.
</noscript>
<!-- service is in read write mode -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the history saved in the browser if you're doing this in Python?

Comment: @Barmar, I feel like this should be able to be done all in one request, per Ben's comment on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057847/https-post-request-python-returning-csv]

Comment: As you can see, it's not actually returning the CSV file. It's returning an HTML page containing JavaScript that starts a download. You need to send your request to the URL in the `window.location.replace()` call.

Comment: Excellent, this is getting me somewhere. I need to submit my post request to the ht tps://login.website in: `window.location.replace('https://login.website...` ?

Comment: I have submitted it to this new address, but I do not have JS enabled, as I am running it from Python. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need JS, you just need to emulate what the JS sends to the server You probably need to send the cookie used for the login session.

Comment: Thanks for your help back here Barmar. I really appreciate it.